# Nextjs 13 fetch from DB in a client component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am having an issue making my Navbar component in Nextjs 13 doing two things at the same time:

- **fetch** the currently logged in user from **DB**
- open/close hamburger mobile menu using **useState** (TailwindUI React header - https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/elements/headers#component-27e5f71ced91b88e3f6b59ca69033a83)

When a user is logged, Navbar needs to know the DB user to render an appropriate icon with popup menu. Also, when screen has a mobile width, the menu hides and a hamburger menu button shows up.

I understand that you cannot use useState on server components. What I don't understand is how to fetch my action.

How do I refactor this so I can fetch the user from DB and also use state in my component?

Navbar.tsx

```tsx
'use client'

import { Dialog } from '@headlessui/react'
import {
    Bars3Icon,
    XMarkIcon
} from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'
import { User } from '@prisma/client'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { UserAvatar } from './navbar/UserAvatar'
import getCurrentUser from '@/app/actions/getCurrentUser'

const Navbar = async () => {
    const [mobileMenuOpen, setMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

    return (
        <header className="bg-slate-50">
            <nav className="mx-auto flex max-w-7xl items-center justify-between p-6 lg:px-8" aria-label="Global">
                {/* logo */}
                <div className="flex">
                    <a href="#" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5">
                        <span className="sr-only">Your Company</span>
                        <img className="h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                {/* mobile menu */}
                <div className="flex lg:hidden">
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className="-m-2.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2.5 text-gray-700"
                        onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(true)}>
                        <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                        <Bars3Icon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </button>
                </div>
                {/* menu items */}
                <div className="hidden lg:flex lg:gap-x-12">
                    <a href="#" className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
                        Features
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
                        Marketplace
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
                        Company
                    </a>
                </div>
                {/* auth buttons */}
                <div className='hidden lg:flex'>
                    {currentUser ? (
                        <UserAvatar />
                    ) : (
                        <Link href='/sign-in' className="hidden lg:flex lg:flex-1 lg:justify-end">
                            Sign In <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>
                        </Link>
                    )}
                </div>
            </nav>
...
```

getCurrentUser.ts

```ts
import prisma from "@/app/lib/prismadb";
import { User } from "@prisma/client";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import { authOptions } from "../lib/auth";

const getCurrentUser: () => Promise<User | null> = async () => {
    try {
        const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

        if (!session?.user?.email) {
            return null;
        }

        const currentUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: {
                email: session.user.email as string
            }
        });

        if (!currentUser) {
            return null;
        }

        return currentUser;
    } catch (error: any) {
        return null;
    }
};

export default getCurrentUser;
```

Comment: Have you considered using client-side `useSession` hook? https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#usesession

Comment: @IgorDanchenko Yes, but I still need to call the database, which is not a client-side operation. useSession is just a part of the action.

Comment: You can store user info in NextAuth session upon successful authentication (unless it contains some sensitive data that should not be stored in cookies). This way you’d need to fetch data from db only once during authentication.